# What is the simplest way to find smallest subarray containing at least one element from each of the other arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, javascript-objects

What is the simplest way to find the smallest subarray containing at least one element from each of the other arrays in JS?

For example, for arrays `[1,2], [1,3], [4]` the result should be `[1,4]`, it contains 1 from the first and second array, and 4 from the third array

Comment: that is a nice question. have you tried anything?

Comment: You just create a set of first element in each sub-array?

Comment: [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr)

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate all numbers, Build an `counts` object with number as key and value as their frequency of appearance in array.
2. Use `map` on array, Each sub array find out item which has max count (more frequent item).
3. Use `Set` to remove duplicate entries to get the smallest sub array.

```js
const smallsub = (arr) => {
  const counts = {};
  arr.flat().forEach((num) => (counts[num] = (counts[num] ?? 0) + 1));

  const items = arr.map((nums) =>
    nums.reduce((max, num) => (counts[num] > counts[max] ? num : max))
  );

  return [...new Set(items)];
};

const arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [4]];

console.log(smallsub(arr));
```